# Datatables 1.10 add column for Edit and Delete buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am having trouble understanding how to "add" a column to Datatables 1.10. I want to do this:
[image]

Literally, what does it mean to "add" ? If I understand the documentation, you don't actually add a column, you only overwrite targets with "generated content" using the "columnDefs" function shown here:
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html

This led me to think that now I have to add new "empty" columns from my serverside code just to have a place for my buttons. This seemed wrong or at least not efficient. So then I found [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) with columnDefs.

I basically don't understand the difference but these *seem* to be the only options, neither seem to "create/add" the new column.

```
`"data": "phone",
   "render": {
       "_": "plain",
       "filter": "filter",
       "display": "display"
    }
```

`

**The question is where/how are extra columns added, how are buttons added to the new column.**

*I realize there are similar questions, but most seem geared to 1.9 or assume you understand where the column comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fnRowCallback` to add/update row data.

```
 "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
        // to get datatable settings
        var oSettings = (this.fnSettings) ? this.fnSettings() : this;
        $("td:last", nRow).html('your add and delete button')
        return nRow;
    },
```

**Update:** If you don't want to add fake column  in server code use this line

`$("td:last", nRow).parent().append('<td>your add and delete button</td>')`

this line finds parent `tr` of each row and appends a `td` with buttons

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but same issue. This overwrites the last column of data, not "add" the extra column... so does this mean I have to create a fake column on the server side to over write with buttons?

Comment: yes you have to.  and if you don't want create another column just use `append ` instead of `html` this will not replace the existing last column data. i suggest use fake column

Comment: This is good, it added the outside column, however when 'responsive' activated it pushed the column over too the last shown column in the responsive view. Also an issue of column duplication in pagination. Good try, so close!. ... I haven't tried server side yet.

Comment: if you want this without any issues  then just use fake columns from server side without any issues it will work perfectly